# Relative layout: align by element below, not found id

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

I have 2 two buttons. I need for button which is higher align to button, which is below.

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/menu_start"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btn_menu_scores"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/btn_menu_scores"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_menu_start"
    />
<Button
    android:text="@string/menu_scores"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_menu_scores"/>
```

Error:(20, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignLeft' with value '@id/btn_menu_scores').

This code doesn't work, how fix this?

Comment: Change the order. Declare menu_scores first

Answer (score 2):

Use `@+id/btn_menu_scores` instead of `@id/btn_menu_scores` as id of View :

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_menu_scores"
```